# Change maptype based on button selection using MKMapView

Tags: swiftui, mapkit, mkmapview

So I'm trying to click on a button and change the mapType using the MKMapView API, but I can't seem to achieve it.

So here is what I have, we have the MKMapView file:

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapViewUIKit: UIViewRepresentable {

    // Environment Objects
    @EnvironmentObject var mainViewModel: MainViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject private var mapSettings: MapSettings
    
    // Coordinator function
    final class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        
        // Define this class.
        var parent: MapViewUIKit
    
        // Initialize this class.
        init(_ parent: MapViewUIKit) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        // MARK: Display Annotation
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
            // Unrelated code here.
        }
        
        // MARK: Select Annotation
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
             // Unrelated code here.
        }
    }
    
    //
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        MapViewUIKit.Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    // MARK: CREATE MAP
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        
        // Create map.
        let mapView = MKMapView(frame: .zero)
        
        // Coordinate our delegate.
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        // Set our region for the map.
        mapView.setRegion(DEFAULT_MK_REGION, animated: false)
        
        // Set our map type to standard.
        mapView.mapType = .standard
        
        // Show user location
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        
        return mapView
    }
    
    // MARK: UPDATE MAP
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        updateMapType(uiView)
    }
    
    // Update our map type on selection.
    private func updateMapType(_ uiView: MKMapView) {
        switch mapSettings.mapType {
        case 0:
            if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
                let config = MKStandardMapConfiguration(elevationStyle: elevationStyle(), emphasisStyle: emphasisStyle())
                config.pointOfInterestFilter = MKPointOfInterestFilter.excludingAll
                config.showsTraffic = false
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
        case 1:
            if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
                uiView.preferredConfiguration = MKHybridMapConfiguration(elevationStyle: elevationStyle())
            } else {
                // Fallback
            }
        case 2:
            if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
                uiView.preferredConfiguration = MKImageryMapConfiguration(elevationStyle: elevationStyle())
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    
    // Set the elevation style.
    @available(iOS 16.0, *)
    private func elevationStyle() -> MKMapConfiguration.ElevationStyle {
        if mapSettings.showElevation == 0 {
            return MKMapConfiguration.ElevationStyle.realistic
        } else {
            return MKMapConfiguration.ElevationStyle.flat
        }
    }
    
    // Set the emphasis style.
    @available(iOS 16.0, *)
    private func emphasisStyle() -> MKStandardMapConfiguration.EmphasisStyle {
        if mapSettings.showEmphasisStyle == 0 {
            return MKStandardMapConfiguration.EmphasisStyle.default
        } else {
            return MKStandardMapConfiguration.EmphasisStyle.muted
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have my MapDisplaySheetView, which contains the following buttons:
[image]

Here is the code that I am using:

```
struct MapDisplaySheetView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var mapSettings = MapSettings()
   
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    @State var mapType = 0
    @State var showElevation = 0
    @State var showEmphasis = 0
    @State var mapDisplay: [String] = [
        "Standard",
        "Hybrid",
        "Image",
    ]
    @State var mapElevation: [String] = [
        "Realistic",
        "Flat",
    ]
    @State var mapEmphasis: [String] = [
        "Default",
        "Muted",
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            
            // MARK: MapType
            HStack {
                ForEach(mapDisplay, id: \.self) { item in
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            VStack {
                                Button(action: {
                                    switch item {
                                      case "Standard": mapSettings.mapType = 0
                                      case "Hybrid": mapSettings.mapType = 1
                                      case "Image": mapSettings.mapType = 2
                                      default: mapSettings.mapType = 0
                                    }
                                    print("User has selected \(item) map type.")
                                }, label: {
                                    ZStack {
                                        Text(item)
                                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                    }
                                }) //: Button
                            } //: VStack
                        } //: HStack
                    }
                    .onChange(of: mapType) { newValue in
                        mapSettings.mapType = newValue
                        log.info("The new map type is: \(newValue)")
                    }
                } //: ForEach
            } //: HStack
            
            // MARK: Map Elevation
            HStack {
                
                ForEach(mapElevation, id: \.self) { item in
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            VStack {
                                Button(action: {
                                    switch item {
                                      case "Realistic": mapSettings.showElevation = 0
                                      case "Flat": mapSettings.showElevation = 1
                                      default: mapSettings.showElevation = 0
                                    }
                                    print("User has selected \(item) map elevation.")
                                }, label: {
                                    ZStack {
                                        Text(item)
                                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                    }
                                }) //: Button
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                ForEach(mapEmphasis, id: \.self) { item in
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            VStack {
                                Button(action: {
                                    switch item {
                                      case "Default": mapSettings.showEmphasisStyle = 0
                                      case "Muted": mapSettings.showEmphasisStyle = 1
                                      default: mapSettings.showEmphasisStyle = 0
                                    }
                                    print("User has selected \(item) map emphasis.")
                                }, label: {
                                    ZStack {
                                        Text(item)
                                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                    }
                                }) //: Button
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } //: HStack
        }
    }
}

// Mapping
final class MapSettings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var mapType = 0
    @Published var showElevation = 0
    @Published var showEmphasisStyle = 0
}
```

I am attempting to use `case 0` for the top 3 buttons, which are the `mapType` and then `case 1` for the bottom 2 left buttons and then `case 2` for the bottom 2 right buttons, but I can't seem to get the map to update at all, which I believe there is an issue inside `MapViewUIKit` and got the `mapType` is set.

Could the issue be with `mapView.mapType = .standard`?

I am using this guide as an example: https://holyswift.app/new-mapkit-configurations-with-swiftui/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change your settings to a struct (you don't need a reference type in this situation):

```
struct MapSettings {
    var mapType = 0
    var showElevation = 0
    var showEmphasisStyle = 0
}
```

Then fix the `@ObservedObject` to:

```
@State var mapSettings = MapSettings()
```

Then you can do

```
struct MapViewUIKit: UIViewRepresentable {
    let mapSettings: MapSettings
```

`updateUIView` will be called when `mapSettings` has changed from the last time this View was init, and then you can use the new values to make any changes to `MKMapView` if required.

Another mistake is `Coordinator(self)`, self is just a value which is immediately discarded after SwiftUI updates so that won't work, try this structure instead:

```
struct MyMapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var userTrackingMode: MapUserTrackingMode
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        context.coordinator.mapView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        // MKMapView has a strange design that the delegate is called when setting manually so we need to prevent an infinite loop
        context.coordinator.userTrackingModeChanged = nil
        uiView.userTrackingMode = userTrackingMode == .follow ? MKUserTrackingMode.follow : MKUserTrackingMode.none
        context.coordinator.userTrackingModeChanged = { mode in
            userTrackingMode = mode == .follow ? MapUserTrackingMode.follow : MapUserTrackingMode.none
        }
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        
        lazy var mapView: MKMapView = {
            let mv = MKMapView()
            mv.delegate = self
            return mv
        }()
        
        var userTrackingModeChanged: ((MKUserTrackingMode) -> Void)?
        
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didChange mode: MKUserTrackingMode, animated: Bool) {
            userTrackingModeChanged?(mode)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @malhal, this helps so much - I have to look in `makeUIView` I have `mapView.mapType = .standard` but if I switch it over to `mapView.mapType = mapSettings.mapType` I get the following error: "Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'MKMapType'" - I have to see how I can actually assign it to be the maptype.

Comment: just remove it from makeUIView, update will be called right after that anyway.

Comment: thank you! I will try that later today, much appreciated for the help.